# Save Powershell Shell Studio 2015 to TFS

Tags: powershell, powershell-studio

Does anyone know how to check in PowerShell Studio Project to TFS in Visual Studio?
As you can see in my PowerShell Editor all of the Source Control commands are grayed out. I downloaded and installed the mssi file for Visual Studio 2015 but I can not seem to open it from Visual Studio to check it in? 
Image of my Editor:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra setting under the options (view tab on the ribbon > options) then on the options window the bottom tab on the left is 'Source Control'.

Make sure 'enable source control' is checked.